# Regex for alphanumerictextwith_yyyymmddhhmmss.xml

Tags: c#, regex

I need to check the filename with the following pattern;
`ABC_123_ABC_ABC_yyyymmddhhmmss.XML`

I wrote this regex

```
ABC_123_ABC_ABC_(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[13579][26]|[2468][048])00)|(?:[0-9]{2}(?:(?:[13579][26])|(?:[2468][048]|0[48]))))(?:(?:(?:09|04|06|11)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30))|(?:(?:01|03|05|07|08|10|12)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]))|(?:02(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]))))|(?:[0-9]{4}(?:(?:(?:09|04|06|11)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30))|(?:(?:01|03|05|07|08|10|12)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]))|(?:02(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-8])))))(?:0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(?:[0-5][0-9]){2}.XML
```

It was working in regex tester but not in c# code.

[Here is my regex online tester with full match](https://regex101.com/r/gN1eD8/7)

[here is my Code](http://rextester.com/YQET21321)

**Code**

```
private static bool IsCorrectFileName(string fILENAME)
{
    string filenamePattern = "ABC_123_ABC_ABC_(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[13579][26]|[2468][048])00)|(?:[0-9]{2}(?:(?:[13579][26])|(?:[2468][048]|0[48]))))(?:(?:(?:09|04|06|11)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30))|(?:(?:01|03|05|07|08|10|12)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]))|(?:02(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]))))|(?:[0-9]{4}(?:(?:(?:09|04|06|11)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30))|(?:(?:01|03|05|07|08|10|12)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]))|(?:02(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-8])))))(?:0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(?:[0-5][0-9]){2}.XML";
    Regex filenameRegex = new Regex(filenamePattern);
    return filenameRegex.IsMatch(filenamePattern);
}
```

Comment: Provide sample scenario here.

Comment: Does it work if you change the last statement to `return filenameRegex.IsMatch(fILENAME);` ?

Comment: Alternative approach: Parse the filename with regex, but use capture groups (hour, minute, etc.) and validate the range (0-24, 0-59, days per month) in code. No way you can make sure this works with leap years too.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience I would avoid as much as possible using regex. They quickly become incomprehensible and are hard to debug.

This is why I would rather foster an implementation without them:

```
private static readonly string prefix = "ABC_123_ABC_ABC_";
private static readonly string dateFormat = "yyyyMMddHHmmss";
private static readonly string extension = ".xml";

private static bool IsCorrectFileName(string filename)
{
    DateTime dummy;
    return filename.StartsWith(prefix) &&
           DateTime.TryParseExact(filename.Substring(prefix.Length, dateFormat.Length), dateFormat, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dummy) &&
           filename.EndsWith(extension);
}
```

By using `DateTime.TryParseExact` you get the benefit for free for all date odities like leap year, 30/31 month ending, etc.